# Border not display on next row for split-column-data

Tags: ms-word, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a model xml data:
[Model data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUIB1.png)

I have been using split-column-data: to display column dynamically as I have some data with multiple different column. The thing is the border between each rows is missing. `<?split-column-data:Test?> <?TestValue?>` This is how i display the Test column dynamically. below are my RTF template from word

[RTF template in words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0lEq.png)

I keep getting this:
[Row border is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoRIL.png)

And the ideal out would be: [ideal output with row border missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJA3.png)

Sorry for my bad english, but I need help please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already tried all the standard boarder stuff in Word, you can insert a nested table for each field (table within a table). Change the parent cell to have 0 margins/padding. Keep the for-each/end-for-each in the parent table.